# How to install and use quarto in RStudio terminal?

Tags: terminal, rstudio, quarto

I have a initialized a standard R-project in RStudio. I installed `quarto` package and can use the related R commands, such as `quarto_version()` or `quarto_render("index.qmd")`. But in my `terminal` RStudio says there is no "quarto".

I like to create quarto projects and render project from Terminal.

https://quarto.org/docs/projects/quarto-projects.html

[image]

Comment: You can try to install quarto from the R Studio Terminal with `pip install quarto`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some trials, I installed https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/ again, restart RStudio. Now `quarto --version` etc. works in the terminal.